# Retrieve in-app purchase price via HTTP request or similar

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to add in-app purchases both on iOS and Android to my app for specific items. These will be the same price across platforms. I have a website that loads these items. I want to display the cost of the item for the user. Is there anyway for me to query the app store using an HTTP request to get the price of each item in a specified app store locale from my website incase the price changes? I don't really want to hardcode the value!

Comment: In an iOS app you use an `SKProductsRequest` to retrieve the product details from store kit. The product detail includes the localised price based on the user's App Store account. I assume that there is something similar in Android.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yeah I know, but I'm asking about retrieving the price on my website.

Comment: Oh. Ok. I don't believe that there is any official web service from Apple for this.